# Etymology of azimuth from EZM of Arabic/Hebrew?

Tags: etymology

Dictionary says *azimuth* is from Arabic *el-samut*. I have doubts. Otherwise *alchemy* would have been *achemy*.

There is a Arabic/Hebrew word [عظم / עצם / EZM ] which means *bone*.

I am not familiar with the historical progression of the Arabic word. I understand the Hebrew word though.

[ עצם / עצמ = bone] has been used in Hebrew to connote *intrinsic*, *basic*, *intensity* property.

e.g.

- אלך בעצמי
  ELeKh B-EZM-I
  = I shall go {by myself / on my own}.

In Genesis 29, when Lavan told Jacob/Yaqov, the meaning of "intrinsic" may have not totally arrived at yet:

- אך עצמי ובשרי אתה
  yet my-bones and-my-flesh you-are
  = furthermore you are my bones and my flesh

However by the time of Psalms [ עצם / EZM] was associated with the intrinsic self, base-value. Psalm 6:

- ריפאני יי כי נביהלו עצמי ונפשי נביהלה מאד
  heal me LORD as my bones/self/core is-frightened and my breath/soul is frightened

By the time of early and medieval rabbinic era, [ עצם / EZM]  had already taken the modern meaning self/intrinsic/basic. Which is also the time when Jewish and Arab scientists mingled during the scientific era of the Islamic empire.

There are not three questions but ONE. These are the suggestions of areas of research that would provide strong pro/cons to my question. These are not the questions but significant markers, courtesy of my incomplete research, from which you could follow-up on.

- Where azimuth means the base angle component of the 3-D angular vector, are there evidence to show that the term actually originated from [ezm / عظم / עצם / bone] ?
- What did medieval Arabic astronomy texts used to describe the base component of the 3-D angular vector?
- Are there any evidence that *azimuth* could never have originated from  [ezm / عظم / עצם / bone] ?

Comment: "*Otherwise alchemy would have been achemy.*" And *apricot* would have been *alpricot*?

Comment: Of your three questions, only the third could remotely be interpreted as concerning English language and usage  Even there it is such a specialised question that I am not sure ELU is the right place for it.

Comment: This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Specifically try to ask one question that is about English or etymology of English words. The second is definitely not and the others are doubtful.

Comment: “Otherwise alchemy would have been achemy” is a false assumption. The /l/ in the Arabic definite article _al-_ assimilates in Arabic to a following [sun consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_and_moon_letters), like the /s/ in _samt_ (pl. _sumūt_), but not to a following moon consonant, like the /k/ in _kīmiyāʾ_. So even within Arabic, it’s _as-sumūt_ but _al-kīmiyāʾ_. An etymology for _azimuth_ based on something that means ‘directions’ seems more likely than one based on something that means ‘bone/self’. I don’t know Hebrew, but where would the _-ut_ ending come from with /EZM/?

Comment: What 3 questions. For goodness' sake there are not three questions but ONE. These are the suggestions of areas of research that would provide strong pro/cons to my question. These are not the questions but significant markers, courtesy of my incomplete research, from which you could follow-up on.

Comment: And then there’s the fact that ([according to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/سمت#Arabic), at least), _samt/sumūt_ is actually used in Arabic astrology to mean ‘azimuth’ (and also in the words for ‘zenith’ and ‘nadir’, of which the former is a rather severely mangled form of _samt_ itself). Whether that’s also true of Mediaeval Arabic, I cannot say; but it would seem a bit far-fetched if Modern Arabic had started to use the word based only on the etymology of the European word.

Comment: In Hebrew and Arabic, suffixes and prefixes and vowelization are means to declension. [עצימת עיניים / ezimeth einaim] = turning eye = turning a blind-eye. [עצימות מעט / azimuth m'et] = little-bit intense.

Comment: For all we do not know, zenith could have been from [זין], the pinnacle of a certain memorial [זכר] organ, to which the arabs and byzantines were too embarrassed to admit.

Comment: *Summit* can be from SMT, but *zenith* probably not from SMT.

Comment: *Nadir* corresponds not to nazir but to Arabic nadir نادر and Hebrew nadir נדיר. Both Arabic and Hebrew nadir means rare, infrequent, low, scarce. Whereas Nazir in arabic means "corresponding" - I think you are confusing modern association/explanation with etymology in the wiktionary entry.

Comment: [*Zenith*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=zenith) comes from Arabic *samt*: Why can't that be SMT? Arabic *samt* to Medieval Latin *senit* to Old French *cenith* to French *zénith*, English *zenith*. Don't ask me how the 't' turned into a 'th', but this seems a pretty well-documented pathway.

Comment: @Helmar This is exactly the kind of question that ELU was created to address. If this is not on topic then we should change the site description to "is it a or an?".

Comment: Have you looked at [Fazari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibr%C4%81h%C4%ABm_al-Faz%C4%81r%C4%AB) or [Al Naziri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Nayrizi)'s treatise on the spherical astrolabe? Arab interest is spherical geometry centered on the qibla calculation, although celestial navigation was an Arab tradition predating Islam.

Comment: @BlessedGeek The American Heritage Dictionary has an addendum chapter on Semitic roots of English words. Many of these words may have come to English via other languages that may have had sound changes before they arrived in English. I would check that dictionary for ZMT and SMT and similars to see what other kind of English words they lead to (to see plausibility of any phonetic pathway).

Comment: @Mitch I was merely advocating for a better focus. The second question is surely not about English.

Comment: The second question surely informs the other two. It's all one question as the author states: here are some doubts about and alternate derivations of an English word, and here are some nuanced subquestions about them. No need to be so literal minded. Sure, maybe there could be better focus, but so could the Hubble space telescope.

Comment: Maybe move this to [Linguistics.se]?

Comment: Helmar - there is NO 2nd question. There is only one question.

Answer (score 3):

Azimuth comes from the Spanish word **acimut** (end of 13th century, Alfonso X's reign), itself derived from the arabic *al-sumût* (or *az-samt*), meaning both «the path» and «horizon direction».

*EDIT*: Quote from [Spanish wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/azimut) for "azimut":

> Del árabe السموت (as-sumūt), plural de سمت (samt, "vértice").
>   Compárese el doblete cénit, zénit, así como el francés azimut, el
>   inglés azimuth, el italiano azzimutto o el portugués azimute

The French CNTRL (Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales) refers to the same [origin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/azimut):

> Emprunté à l'espagnol "acimut", fin xiiies. (Alfonse X, le Sage ds
>   Cor.) lui-même de l'arabe sumût, pluriel de samt « le chemin » (Lok.
>   no1818, FEW t. 19, p. 153).

Comment: You are providing an answer to which I specifically expressed my doubts in the question.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: I edited my answer to provide Spanish and French sources.

Comment: The etymological dictionary by Rabbi Ernest Klein (Klein's Comprehensive Etymological Dictionary of the English Language, Elsevier 1971) is a particularly good reference for Semitic roots of English words. It gives the origin of azimuth as: fr. Arab. *as-sumut*, pl. of *as-samt*, 'the way', fr. *as-*, assimilated form of *al-*, 'the', and *samt*, 'way'. (I omitted the diacritical marks)